# 64-bit nvidia driver on 32-bit machine

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 x86 version. I have two video cards (one integrated and one Nvidia on inter core-i5 processor with 3GB ram). Right now my display resolution is very poor as I can't use the graphic card. I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

to install driver for Nvidia Geforce but failed.

```
$ lshw -c video
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: nVidia Corporation
       vendor: nVidia Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff(prefetchable) memory:d0000000-d1ffffff(prefetchable) ioport:3000(size=128) memory:f1080000-f10fffff(prefetchable)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1400000-f17fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff(prefetchable) ioport:4000(size=64)
```

As shown in the output (width:64 bit), shall I install x64 version of Ubuntu to make drivers work? or what should i do to make them work ?

I am following [this Ubuntu Forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1467074) for installation. When I execute `sudo gdm-stop` , I am not getting terminal or any screen. Even on CTRL+ALT+F2 I just get a blank screen with no prompt. What should I do?

Comment: use 'jockey' not manual installation discussions.  it's the 'supported' way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

The 'width' mentioned in the output addresses the width of the device,
this has nothing to do with having 32bit or 64bit driver so using 64 bit ubuntu will make no difference to your video drivers.

Which Geforce graphics card do you have? If it is a hybrid card you may have some success using Bumblebee. [Installation instructions here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936)

Answer (score 0):

No.  You use the 32 bit binary driver for the best performance.  Generally, `jockey-gtk` in the terminal is the way to install binary drivers on ubuntu.  You could install x64 and the 64-bit driver...but you don't get 64 bit driver on 32 bit machines.

Comment: Thanks..I am reinstalling the driver and will update the results.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. These answers are wrong. You need to install bumblebee instead of NVIDIA drivers. Bumblebee is used with NVIDIA Optimus Graphic cards. Your output shows two video cards. Remove NVIDIA Drivers and install bumblebee.